# How can I use callback method in Overwrite storage class for django save method?

Tags: python, django, overwrite, django-storage

I want invoke a callback method once I try to call save mthod of my overwrite method, but is doesn't seem to work.

below is my code.

```
class OverwriteStorage(Storage):

def save(self, name, content, max_length=None, callback=None):
        """
        Save new content to the file specified by name. The content should be
        a proper File object or any Python file-like object, ready to be read
        from the beginning.

        This method is modified to take care of callbacks for S3 storage class of amazon.
        So that user specific callback can be accommodated.
        :param name: name of the file.
        :param content: content of the file
        :param max_length: max length of the file.
        :param callback: callback method.
        :return:
        """

        # Get the proper name for the file, as it will actually be saved.
        if name is None:
            name = content.name

        if not hasattr(content, 'chunks'):
            content = File(content, name)

        name = self.get_available_name(name, max_length=max_length)

        return self._save(name, content, callback=callback)
```

but when I am trying to call this:

```
file.file_location.save(name_of_the_file, File(open(str(name_of_the_file), 'r')),callback=ProgressPercentageUpload(name_of_the_file, size_of_the_file))
```

It throws below error:

```
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.